# 'Confirm it' vs 'confirm' to you

Tags: pronouns, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

> I will probably visit Berlin tomorrow; I can confirm (**it**) tomorrow morning. Will you be home?

Could you please tell me if the above sentence is correct and if the use of ***it*** is necessary?

Also, should I add the expression ***to you*** to the sentence, i.e.

> I will probably visit Berlin tomorrow; I can confirm (**it**) to you tomorrow morning. Will you be home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the direct object "it" and the indirect object "to you" are optional: it's fine with or without them.

If I expressed the direct object, I would probably say "confirm this" rather than "confirm it"; but I don't think I can explain why I would make this choice.

Comment: I agree though I  think “to you” is unnecessary and sounds awkward. “This” is better than “it” because “it” would refer to either the subject or object of the previous sentence. You are confirming neither “I” nor “Berlin” but the whole of the previous sentence.